# Microsoft Bot Framework: Ask again without restarting dialog

Tags: c#, dialog, botframework

I have a bot, that will look for a person in a database. If that person is not a known name, I would like to have the Bot ask again: "Name is unknown, please give the name again"

Here are the steps I've done now:

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());   
    }
.... (more code here)
```

in the RootDialog:

```
   public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
   {
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);

    }
    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("help") 
            || message.Text.ToLower().Contains("support") 
            || message.Text.ToLower().Contains("problem"))
        {
            await context.Forward(new SupportDialog(), this.ResumeAfterSupportDialog, message, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Call(new SearchDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
        }
    }
```

And in the SearchDialog:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"Hi {context.Activity.From.Name}, Looking for someone?.");
        var SearchFormDialog = FormDialog.FromForm(this.BuildSearchForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
        context.Call(SearchFormDialog, this.ResumeAfterSearchFormDialog);
    }


private IForm<SearchQuery> BuildSearchForm()
    {
        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<SearchQuery> processSearch = async (context, persoon) =>
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"There we go...");
        };

        return new FormBuilder<SearchQuery>()
            .Field(nameof(SearchQuery.Name))
            .Message($"Just a second...")
            .AddRemainingFields()
            .OnCompletion(processSearch)
            .Build();
    }


private async Task ResumeAfterSearchFormDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<SearchQuery> result)
    {
        try
        {
            var searchQuery = await result;

            var found = await new BotDatabaseEntities().GetAllWithText(searchQuery.Name);
            var resultMessage = context.MakeMessage();

            var listOfPersons = foundPersons as IList<Person> ?? foundPersons.ToList();

            if (!listOfPersons.Any())
            {
                await context.PostASync($"No one found");
            }
            else if (listOfPersons.Count > 1)
            {
                resultMessage.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;
                resultMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                this.ShowNames(context, listOfPersons.Select(foundPerson => foundPerson.FullName.ToString()).ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                await OnePersonFound(context, listOfPersons.First(), resultMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (FormCanceledException ex)
        {
            string reply;
            reply = ex.InnerException == null ? "You have canceled the operation";
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
    }
```

and this is the SearchQuery:

```
[Serializable]
public class SearchQuery
{
    [Prompt("Please give the {&} of the person your looking for.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now. When I give a name that does not exist, I don't want to restart the conversation but only that the Bot asks the question again after this.

```
if (!listOfPersons.Any())
        {
            await context.PostASync($"No one found");
        }
```

Really no clue on how to fix that.

Comment: So, you don't want to call again the SearchFormDialog?

Comment: Well, no actually. Because then the dialog wil start again:
- Hi Brian, please give the name.
"John Doe"
- Name was not found.
- Hi Brian, please give the name.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I fixed it now like this:

```
if (!listOfPersons.Any())
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"Sorry, no one was found with this text");
                var SearchFormDialog = FormDialog.FromForm(this.BuildSearchForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
                context.Call(SearchFormDialog, this.ResumeAfterSearchFormDialog);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use validation delegate to check the given name is valid or not

```
private IForm<SampleForm> BuildFeedbackModelForm()
    {
        var builder = new FormBuilder<SampleForm>();
        return builder.Field(new FieldReflector<SampleForm>(nameof(SampleForm.Question))
                .SetType(typeof(string))
                .SetDefine(async (state, field) => await SetOptions(state, nameof(SampleForm.Answer), field))
                .SetValidate(async (state, value) => await ValidateFdResponseAsync(value, state, nameof(SampleForm.Answer)))).Build();

    }

    private async Task<bool> SetOptions(SampleForm state, string v, Field<SampleForm> field)
    {
    return true;
    }

    private async Task<ValidateResult> ValidateFdResponseAsync(object response, SyncfusionBotFeedbackForm state, string v)
    {
        bool isValid = false; // chcek if valid


        ValidateResult validateResult = new ValidateResult
        {
            IsValid = isValid,
            Value = isValid?locresult:null
        };
        if (!isValid)
            validateResult.Feedback = $"message to user.";
        return validateResult;
    }
```